# pandas.concat on categorical dataframe takes too much memory

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframe, `df1` & `df2`, each of 5GB+, each of them are categorical. the categories have some overlapping, while each have some extra categories.

when I do `pd.concat([df1, df2])` or `df1.append(df2)`, the memory blows on a 64GB machine.

Is there any way to minimize the memory consumption? I would like to see it using around 10GB memory, trading off time will be fine.

Comment: Could you elaborate more when you say "the categories have some overlapping"? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Can you insert the data into a pre-allocated dataframe? I would think this would be a much more appropriate method in terms of memory and time than concatenation, which generates a concatenated copy of the two dataframes.